# Rails bin when installing from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install rails from the github repo (as the action cable framework doesn't depend on celluloid anymore) using this Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', :git => 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

But I cannot do this

```
$ rails new appname
```

The binary/executable isn't available. Any possible way of creating a new rails app like this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @Tobias, Yes I did. [This link](http://bundler.io/git.html) say I should run Bundler.setup. I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [this](http://bundler.io/v1.11/bundler_setup.html)?

Comment: Hi **prajwaldp** not clear your question, you not find Gemfile without rails app.

Comment: @Web, I can create the gemfile first and then run bundle install like [this](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/managing-multiple-rails-versions).

Comment: Since rails has had a very recent release that gets rid of many dependencies, I just had to install the latest beta release. That does not anwser the question though and it still holds I guess.